# Save a field for every SiteTree item

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have an extension that sets up search fields like this:

```php
     public function onBeforeWrite(){                
       parent::onBeforeWrite();        
       $this->getOwner()->SearchContent = $this->collateSearchContent();
     }
```

Which works ok, except only on new or updated pages.  I want to loop through the SiteTree and save the SearchContent for each.

In my task I do this:

```php
     foreach (SiteTree::get() as $item) {
       $the_text = $item->collateSearchContent();   
       # Previously:  $item->getOwner()->SearchContent = $the_text;
       $item->SearchContent = $the_text;
       $item->write();
     }
```

I get the error:

```
 Caught exception: Object->__call(): the method 'collateSearchContent' does not exist on 'Page'
```

So, nearly there. But it's not using the SiteTree object to find the method.  How do I access the sitetree object?

Answer (score 2):

`$this->getOwner()` works in the first scenario because `$this` is an instance of [`Extension`](https://api.silverstripe.org/5/SilverStripe/Core/Extension.html), and `$this->getOwner()` returns a `SiteTree` record.

In the second scenario, `$item` is the `SiteTree` record, so `getOwner()` isn't needed.

What's more, `save()` is not going to work, because that method doesn't exist on `SiteTree` (see [API docs](https://api.silverstripe.org/5/SilverStripe/CMS/Model/SiteTree.html)).

```php
foreach (SiteTree::get() as $item) {
    $item->SearchContent = $item->collateSearchContent();
    $item->write();
}
```

Comment: I made these changes, and still get the same error.  I edited the question a bit to help narrow it down to accessing the method in the extension.

Comment: Sounds like the `collateSearchContent()` method is defined somewhere else then. I'm not aware of that method, so I'm guessing it's a method you have added? The method needs to be public to be accessed like this. It also needs to be either on the `Page` class or on an `Extension` class applied to `Page`.

Comment: It's defined on the SiteTree extension.  Making it public (doh!) made the loop work setting up the search.  The $item className is Page or BlockPage, not SiteTree, but they are inheriting the method from it of course.

Comment: Presumably `BlockPage` is a subclass of `Page` which is a subclass of `SiteTree` ;p For simplicity's sake we can say they are "`SiteTree` records"

Comment: Keep in mind that SiteTree is Staged into Stage/Live. If you just call ->write() it will only write it to draft. You'll also need to publish it